# Create a file on another dir using PHP

Tags: php

i want to create a file inside another directory called "files".

My Server looks like this:

```
root:
    createfile.php
    files:
         file1.txt
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$myfile = fopen("../files/file2.txt", "w")or die("Unable to open file!");
```

But when I run mu code it gives me this error:

```
Warning: fopen(../files/file2.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\createfile.php on line 4
```

Comment: minus the `../` part and your good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PHP file and the folder you want to create the file in exist in the same folder, there is no need for "../". The meaning currently is that files directory is at the same level as root directory. Just remove that and it should work.

```
$myfile = fopen("files/file2.txt", "w")or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for create new file.

```
<?php
echo file_put_contents("test.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
?>
```